# How to change Android application UI in background

Tags: android, background, lifecycle

How can I change fragment view (need to hide webview) then application goes to background (user push home button)

I'm using ProcessLifecycleOwner to detect background

```
@OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
    public void appInBackground(){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                view.findViewById(R.id.webview).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

    }
```

webview sets to invisible then application goes from background and user can see last view before background

Maybe I can detect home button click, and hide webview before background?

Comment: whenever you press home button or back button the  onStop() call back lifecycle will be tiggered. you can handle over there.

Comment: I cant't use onStop because fragment open activity and fragment not active in that moment and onStop detect it.

Comment: you want to change the fragment when the application goes background right?

Comment: yes. appInBackground detect background, and set invisible to webview, but invisible apples then app goes back to life

Comment: Try to use onResume for analyze and change views

Comment: yes, but all this changes will see user